# Java EE or Netbeans with Glassfish?

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, sun

I've downloaded Netbeans with Glassfish and installed it.

Do I have to download Java EE then from Sun's site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't have to... Everything you need is included in the netbeans + glassfish bundle...

Answer (score 2):

J2EE (now Java EE) is a specification. Glassfish is a server that implements the specification.

Comment: plz look at my new comment on the first post.